# Why does yarn remove "private": "true", in my package.json?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package.json, yarn-v3

When I run `yarn` in a directory that includes a package.json file with a `"private": "true",` field, this line is silently removed. This behavior is in yarn 3.1.0, but not in npm 8.5.5, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running `yarn` seems to be type sensitive!

- `"private": "true",` -> {a string} is removed.
- `"private": true,` -> {a boolean} is untouched, and should work as intended.